# How to clear div elements on load

Tags: javascript, html

I want to add a hyperlink on the ribbon. I was able to add the hyperlink to the existing div. Since the ribbon is getting refreshed for every action i do, the Hyperlinks are getting increased.

How can i clear the div and make only one link available.

I am using the following code:

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a'); 
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");  
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Comment: Replace the last line with tehse two lines may be? mydiv.innerHTML = ""; mydiv.appendChild(aTag);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var aTag = "<a href='yourlink.htm' > </a>";
document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHtml = aTag ;
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery has the [empty()](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) function.  If you're just using pure JS you can always add the line `mydiv.innerhtml = ""` before you add the `<a>` tag.

Comment: yeah, that's why I supplied the pure javascript one as well.

Answer (score 1):

this may work for you :

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a'); 
aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");  
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";
mydiv.innerHTML="";
mydiv.innerHTML=aTag;
```

Comment: How can i call a function inside the same js file on click of the hyperlink.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that **ribbon** is **"myDiv"**

```
mydiv.innerHTML = ""
```

before

```
mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var mydiv = document.getElementById("myDiv");
var aTag = document.createElement('a');

aTag.setAttribute('href',"yourlink.htm");
aTag.innerHTML = "link text";

if( mydiv.firstChild ){
  mydiv.replaceChild(aTag, mydiv.firstChild);
}else{
  mydiv.appendChild(aTag);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This method removes not only child (and other descendant) elements, but also any text within the set of matched elements. This is because, according to the DOM specification, any string of text within an element is considered a child node of that element. Consider the following HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello">Hello</div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```

We can target any element for removal:

```
$('.hello').empty();
```

This will result in a DOM structure with the Hello text deleted:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="hello"></div>
  <div class="goodbye">Goodbye</div>
</div>
```